# Explain the time complexity of these grouping functions

Tags: c++, algorithm, inheritance, time-complexity

Here I have 800 derived classes of `Base` and a list of 8000000 objects of these types, which can be of any order.  The goal is to separate the list into the 800 types as efficiently as possible.  Here I have written two functions to do that.  The first is supposedly in O(M*logN) time, where M is the size of the list, and N = number of concrete derived classes of `Base`, and the second is supposedly in O(M) time.  But when I time the output, the second is clearly not log800 times faster than the first.  Did I get the time complexity wrong here?  Better yet, is there a faster function that makes this whole comparison a moot point?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>

class Base {
public:
    virtual std::size_t ID() const = 0;
};

template <std::size_t N> class Derived : public Base {
    virtual std::size_t ID() const override {return N;}
};

const std::size_t NumDerivedTypes = 800;

template <typename Iterator>
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::list<typename Iterator::value_type>> separateWithMap (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::list<typename Iterator::value_type>> map;
    while (first != last) {
        const auto it = map.find ((*first)->ID());
        if (it != map.end()) {
            it->second.emplace_back(*first);
        }
        else {
            std::list<typename Iterator::value_type> newGroup = {*first};
            map.emplace ((*first)->ID(), newGroup);
        }
        first++;
    }
    return map;
}

template <typename Iterator>
std::array<std::list<typename Iterator::value_type>, NumDerivedTypes> separateWithArray (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    std::array<std::list<typename Iterator::value_type>, NumDerivedTypes> array;
    while (first != last) {
        array[(*first)->ID()].emplace_back(*first);
        ++first;
    }
    return array;
}

// ------------------------------- Testing -------------------------------
template <std::size_t N>
void build (std::list<Base*>& weapons) {
    weapons.emplace_back(new Derived<N>);
    build<N+1>(weapons);
}

template <>
void build<NumDerivedTypes> (std::list<Base*>&) {}  // End of recursion.

struct Timer {
    const std::clock_t begin = std::clock();
    ~Timer() {
        auto end = std::clock();
        std::cout << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds.\n";
    };
};

int main() {
    // M = scrambled.size(), N = number of concrete derived classes of Base.
    std::list<Base*> scrambled;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        build<0>(scrambled);  // Assume 'scrambled' has many, many elements in some unknown order.
    std::cout << "scrambled.size() = " << scrambled.size() << '\n';  // 8000000

    {
        std::cout << "\nseparateWithMap started:\n";  // O(M*logN) time
        Timer timer;
        const std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::list<Base*>> separated = separateWithMap (scrambled.begin(), scrambled.end());
        std::cout << "separateWithMap ended:\n";
    }
    {
        std::cout << "\nseparateWithArray started:\n";  // O(M) time            
        Timer timer;
        const std::array<std::list<Base*>, NumDerivedTypes> partitioned = separateWithArray (scrambled.begin(), scrambled.end());
        std::cout << "separateWithArray ended:\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
scrambled.size() = 8000000

separateWithMap started.
separateWithMap ended.
30.318 seconds.

separateWithArray started.
separateWithArray ended.
22.869 seconds.
```

By the way, both functions successfully separate the objects into their respective types (tested), but I don't display that in the output, for obvious reasons.

Comment: `I have 800 derived classes of Base`  I was just getting ready to write "no you don't" then I saw ... you do... ooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first is supposedly in O(M*logN) time, where M is the size of the list, and N = number of concrete derived classes of Base

It's not though. `unordered_map` is a hashtable, [lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) and [insertion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) have constant complexity on average. So the first is still `O(M)`. Just with more work than the simple array version.

As a side-note, using `operator[]` would simplify your logic a bit:

```
for (; first != last; ++first) {
    map[(*first)->ID()].emplace_back(*first);
}
```

Exactly like your array version.